Creation of Component Gateway Viewer (CGV) in GCP Dataproc cluster behaves differently
I have a weird context with respect to component gateway viewer (CGV) creation in GCP Dataproc cluster. I create the Dataproc cluster along with CGV via Terraform as described below:
#Cluster is created
resource "google_dataproc_cluster" "mycluster" {
  name     = "mycluster"
  region   = "us-central1"

  ...  #some other properties of the cluster

  software_config {
      override_properties = {
        "dataproc:dataproc.enable_component_gateway" = "true"  #component gateway is enabled
      }

  cluster_config {
    endpoint_config {
            enable_http_port_access = true  #https port is enabled
        }
  }
}

#Component Gateway is associated/created with the above cluster
resource "google_dataproc_cluster_iam_member" "CGV" {
  cluster = google_dataproc_cluster.mycluster.name      <-- Implicit dependency of the above cluster
  role    = "my_custome_role"
  member  = "group:group@example.com"
}

So what happens is:
Let us say: As of now, I have the above dataproc cluster which has component gateway viewer enabled (i.e: being attached with it).
I can view the YARN (Resource Manager) page via browser without any issues.
But if I end up re-creating (by adding/changing a property) the above cluster, the component gateway access is somehow not recreated (in other words: deletion and then re-creation is not happening).
I look at the Terraform plan and it does not list that CGV will be re-created. But the plan says that the cluster will be re-created because of the change(s) that I make.
Clearly I am not able to view the YARN page (when I try to click the YARN lick) after the cluster is re-created. I get 'Forbidden' message in the browser.
But again if I recreate the cluster (by means of changing some properties) one more time, the CGV is created back. This time the TF plan clearly lists about the CGV re-creation.
So this CGV creation is flipped every time I recreate the cluster via TF.
That is: If CGV is associated correctly now, then next time when the cluster is re-created back, CGV is taken off. And then it is attached back, if I re-create the cluster again.
Though the CGV creation clearly has an implicit dependency on the cluster (via cluster property), it does not behave in the way that I expect.
I also tried to make explicit dependency (via: depends_on = [google_dataproc_cluster.mycluster]), it does not work as well.
Some guidance would be greatly appreciated on why this happens.

I think that's because this implicit dependency relies on the name of the cluster which is not changing between recreation of the cluster. Try to add a dependency on an attribute that is changing on every recreation. This might require from you to use some intermediate resource or local value that will use this "always-changing" attribute and then add explicit depends_on with this intermediate to google_dataproc_cluster_iam_member.
